# Facebook addthis won't show all my thumbnails?

Tags: facebook, addthis

Hello I've implemented the `addthis` toolbar on my site and I've noticed it doesn't behave as intended.
There are two issues:

- when I first try to share to facebook  for example 8 thumbnails, all the thumbnails appear but are in the opposite order.
- when I refresh my cache, the elements are displayed in the proper order, butonly the first 3 are ever shown

From the source code I can see all my images are in the page, in the proper order and all of them with `og:image` tags, so I have no idea what more I can do from my side.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem, and hopefully has some advice?

Comment: Share the site in question.

Comment: You can try forcing Facebook to reset it's cache... http://stackoverflow.com/a/7695273/1054225